# Retrieve data from boost::variant using static visitor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I have a static visitor setup like this

```
struct visitor : public boost::static_visitor<std::string&> {

obj& m_data;
visitor(obj& data) : m_data(data) {}

std::string& operator()(key_type_1& k1) const {
return m_data.get(k1);
}

std::string& operator()(key_type_2& k2) const {
return m_data.get(k2);
}

}
```

There are no compilation errors and everything looks good initially.
But, this test case fails -

```
std::string x = boost::apply_visitor(visitor(data1), variant);
std::string y = boost::apply_visitor(visitor(data2), variant);
```

the second call is still trying to retrieve from data1. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Your instantiation of static_visitor with a reference type looks a little bit odd to me.

Comment: thanks, that was it. changed the operator(s) to return void and store the result in a new struct member variable.